# Automatizar DDD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd

Existe uma forma mais rápida de criação de uma estrutura no asp.net mvc usando DDD (plugin ou framework)?

Por exemplo, sempre que criada uma nova entidade, é necessário criar muitos arquivos em diversos projetos e ainda configurar o automapper e o ninject. Existe alguma forma de após criar uma classe base esse restante que de inicio é sempre igual ser gerado "sozinho"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, usando o [MvcScaffolding.VS2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/).

Você terá que escrever seu próprio *Scaffolder*. [Veja aqui como](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/07/mvcscaffolding-creating-custom-scaffolders/).

Se você quiser uma coisa mais dentro do Visual Studio, [pode criar seu *Scaffold* usando o SideWaffle](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio/).